# I'm in my third year, but I'm still not clear with my I'm doing

Tags: phd, computer-science

I'm a PhD student in computer science.

A few days before I started my PhD, my supervisor sent me a new proposal which was a different topic from the one that I proposed in the application. I had no option, rather to agree. After a few months, I started realizing my main supervisor was not specialized in the research area. I started to have a doubt about him. However, with some idea, I passed my proposal defence in my first year. He didn't know what the hell I was doing.

A few months later after my proposal defence, He called me and talked to suggesting to remove him as the supervisor by giving some excuse that he didn't want to simply in the supervisor team without contributing anything. I'm not sure whether this is the right reason or just an excuse to leave me. I changed my supervisor to someone who has no knowledge at all in the area and still doesn't understand the area till now. I had to change my supervisor since the previous supervisor asked me to do so.

Now, I'm in my third year. I'm still not clear with what I'm doing. I'm still working on the idea. The idea is like something to solve a particular problem using a particular approach. I have tried some existing algorithms, it seems it they don't work well. These algorithms have not been applied in my area. I'm benchmarking the results of those algorithms.

I haven't developed any new algorithm so far. I haven't came out with any novel work so far.

What should I do?

Comment: How many supervisors do you have?

Comment: @Aqee, why you put in such situation, why you didnot switch program and work with knowledgable people, all I can say, maybe seek to have knowledgable co-supervisor, it sounds the only option here.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger I have three: (1) The main supervisor knows nothing, we always have meeting. But my main supervisor just asking general things and publications, keep pushing me to publish so that my work is strong enogugh to be considered as a PhD. It seems his only indicator about my work whehter good or not is based on publication, not based on his evaluation. Obviously he cannot evaluate as he deson't know what I'm doing,

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger  (2) Co-supervisor is not an expert in the area. (3) Co-sopuvisor who also doesn't know the area. The probvlem will all of them are they don't really undeerstand what I'm doing, not even trying to understand. The ex-supervisor who brought me in is also like them, that's why he 'left' me. There is no expert in my area at my university as this is a new area.

Comment: @Erik my university is only small. So, not so many people can supervise me. I got the topic from my ex-supervisor who brought me in. My area is new, and that's why he sent a new proposal to me a few days before I started my PhD (as mentioned above). Maybe he interested in that area but has no specialized knowledge. I tried to find external supervisor from other local universities, but I couldn't find someone who has worked in that area.

Comment: @Aqee, I see you seemed you did your effort, I have few questions, how much time left you expect to finish, are you stuck completely, or can seek help online even as I did in my masters. Do you think you are able to graduate with masters and applying somewhere else who is expert in that new area an maybe you can be more productive instead of struggling alone

Comment: @Erik(1) I have around 6 more months to graduate on time. I may need more than that. (2) I'm not even sure whether I stuck completely or not. But, I believe I can do something. The issue here is that, who can tell me whether I'm stuck or not since my supervisors are not helpful. I'm  finding people who I can talk to to give opinion (and here is one of them). (3) I have no idea how to get online help. But, I'm trying to contact some authors in area. (4) In the worst care situation where I cannot proceed at all, I will find another institution but I have a bit phobia to start again.

Comment: @Aqee, may I ask what is your subfield? It is hard to say whether what you did is significant, but the good part I see that you are persistent and you believe you can do it, I think the ideal situation is to find an external support (expert) who can judge. Another aspect as you may know the only one who can make you graduate is your supervisor, they have to be convinced that you did a subtantial work.

Comment: @Erik My sub-field is security. Yes, it suppose to be my supervisor to judge my work. But, he is not be able to do it I think as he deson't know what is going on. Even I explain, he seems not to be able understand. He only concern to ask me publish in top journal. I feel he only judge my work based on publication not his own ability.